# How do I troubleshoot "failed to initialize logging driver" (ECS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

I've created 3 tasks on a cluster. 1 is running fine but I'm getting

```
CannotStartContainerError: Error response from daemon: failed to initialize logging driver: failed to create Cloudwatch log stream: ResourceNotFoundException: The specified log group does not exist. status code: 400, request id: 3bf76715-2188-40d6-8bed-4
```

on the other 2. I shouldn't be getting this error since I've been following tutorial.

It says "the specified log group doesn't exist" but:
[image]

Any insight into this much appreciated.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The more important part of the error is: ResourceNotFoundException: The specified log group does not exist.
The log group you have specified might have been deleted. Make sure the log group exists and try again.

Edit: You can select the `Auto-configure CloudWatch Logs` option to avoid this error.

Comment: Yes, that was it. I had no clue that the log groups didn't exist.

Comment: Been there.. :)

Comment: the log group exists for me. still I get the same error. Is there anything else required here,  permissions perhaps ?

Comment: yes, for me it was a name mismatch between log-group mentioned in container definitions & the actual cloudwatch resource

Comment: The json to add to your task definition is simply `"awslogs-create-group": "true"`. [Good resource on awslogs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/using_awslogs.html)

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to do this via CDK, but don't see a parameter to control that option....

Answer (score 0):

I had the correct Cloudwatch log group name but had to remove it and re-create it before it works.